# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, keras, tuples, prediction

I am running this code in Google Colab and I get this error

This is the code link to Google Colab:

### https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DbeK9Qz_Q31gM6lmERNOaegP2irTuv0a?usp=sharing

And this is the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e258b3312a90> in <module>()
     31 print(f"acc: {val_acc}")
     32 
---> 33 predictions = model.predict([x_test])
     34 
     35 print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1122 predict_step  
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:291 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:642 call
        input_shape = inputs.shape

    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Maybe restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Please include your code, not as a link, but as a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

change

```py
model.predict([x_test])
```

To

```py
model.predict(x_test)
```